# How to automatically keep user remembered in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am building an app in which I would like the users to automatically be remembered on their computers, without having a "remember me" check box.

I read that I may have to call `@user.remember_me!`, but not sure where to call it since the Devise controllers are hidden.

I was considering adding a hidden checkbox field in the sign_in form with the checkbox marked by default, but I was hoping I could do this on the controllers side.

Any idea how this could be done?

Thanks!

Comment: This should help: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/plataformatec-devise/fGHzF1imqJ0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think customizing your devise controller is the way to go here.

Goal: automatically set remember-me for everybody.

First, create a devise sessions controller. Let's tell rails routes about it

**config/routes.rb**

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'sessions'}
```

**app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    params[:user].merge!(remember_me: 1)
    super
  end

end
```

This way, the user's remember me will always be set to true. yay!

You'll then want to edit the login form to not display the remember_me checkbox.

Also, change this in the initializer to something far off:

```
#config.remember_for = 2.weeks
config.remember_for = 1.year
```

Comment: hm, it does not work for me, i look at log and dont see changing of remember_created_at field also i have to login to my app each time after i close browser :(

Comment: May be a good idea to keep the warden scope generalized:
  params[scope_name].merge!(remember_me: 1)

Comment: The configuration for this is in config/initializers/devise.rb

Answer (score 24):

If you read this pull request in devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1513, the sanctioned way to remember by default appears to simply define on your User class:

```
class User
   def remember_me
     (super == nil) ? true : super
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

That should be a persistent option so you can do this on an after create hook for the user since you want it to be a permanent option.

Comment: although wouldnt that the remember_me be only once ... when the record is created? because remember_me would probably expire in 2 weeks, it would not have any effect after 2 weeks ...