# Rails: is it possible to remember user automatically in Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In Devise, I want to automatically remember user's login rather than let them make the choice in the login form. (So we don't show 'remember-me' checkbox in view)

How can I do it?

Find something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417201/how-to-automatically-keep-user-remembered-in-devise)

Comment: It's advisable to let users decide for themselves whether or not they'd want to keep logged into their account from a particular device. Sometimes it's a shared device, like a computer at a workplace or an internet café.

Comment: @Yaw, But in tumblr, there's not such an option. How do they consider this?

Comment: If you think about security, it's a risk you should not take on behalf of your users. Let them decide on that. I wouldn't use an application that makes such critical decisions for me without letting me know. Not too bad would be checking `Remember me` by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make the "remember-me" as a hidden field and always passed 'true' value.