# Devise is not remembering the sign in credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have combed all the docs and how-to's I can find but can't figure this out.  I have a functioning Devise set-up except that after signing out the sign in email field is blank.  The 'remember me' check box is selected no matter if I check it or uncheck it on previous sign-ins.

Here is the config values I have so far:

My sign-in view:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :html => {:class => "" }, as: resource_name, url: user_session_path) do |f| %>
<fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Email", autofocus: true %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Password", autocomplete: "off" %>
    </div>


    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
            <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> Remember Me
        </label>
    </div>
    <% end -%>
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Sign In">
    <%= link_to new_user_password_path,  class: "btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block" do %>Forgot Password<% end %>
    <%= link_to user_registration_path,  class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" do %>Register<% end %>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

My Routes with custom session controller:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations], :controllers => { :registrations => 'users/registrations', :sessions => 'users/sessions' }

class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    current_user.remember_me = true
    super
  end

end
```

Devise initializer:

config.remember_for = 2.weeks

Model:

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :timeoutable

  # http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417201/how-to-automatically-keep-user-remembered-in-devise    
  def remember_me
    true
  end
```

I think thats it - the more I read am I perhaps missing something here like is the email / username sign-in field meant to be populated with the users email / username?

My cookies seem to be empty if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because remember_me comes in params as "on", but is compared to Devise::TRUE_VALUES, which are [true, 1, '1', 't', 'T', 'true', 'TRUE'].

The easiest way is to make it work is to insure your remember_me comes as one of that values. Example of check-box(notice value="1"):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1" checked="checked" />
```

Another way if you want to make it work with "on" value you can add "on" to Devise::TRUE_VALUES. So in your config/initializers/devise.rb just add as the first line:

```
Devise::TRUE_VALUES << ["on"]
```

Comment: That does not work.  My check box HTML is:  <input checked="checked" id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="1">