# Devise remember_me! not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have the following code in my `sessions_controller.rb` file:

```
module V1
  class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

    # POST /sign_in
    def new
      user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email]) if params[:user] 
      if user && user.valid_password?(params[:user][:password])
        sign_in(:user, user)
        current_user.remember_me!
        head 200
      else
        render status: 200, json: {errors: ["Incorrect email / username or password."]}.as_json
      end
    end

    # ...

  end
end
```

The above code seems to work fine, however, after signing in and visiting my `/posts` route and I get an error telling me "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."

The structure of my app:

```
controllers
├── v1
|   ├── users
|   |   ├── registrations_controller.rb
|   |   ├── sessions_controller.rb
|   |   ├── api_controller.rb
|   ├── posts_controller.rb
application_controller.rb
```

In my posts controller I have set `before_action :authenticate_v1_user!`. I'm using rails to build an API and I'm testing the above routes by sending requests from a tool called [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en). I've also tried testing from my AngularJS app (on a different subdomain than the API). Why would I get an error telling me to log in when I just logged in by sending the correct credentials to `/sign_in`. Are there special considerations since this is just an API?

**EDIT:**

My `user.rb` file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments

  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password, confirmation: true, presence: true
  validates :password_confirmation, presence: true
end
```

My `routes.rb` file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions", registrations: "users/registrations" }
  devise_scope :user do
    post "sign_in", to: "v1/users/sessions#new"
    delete "sign_out", to: "v1/users/sessions#destroy"
    post "register", to: "v1/users/registrations#create"
  end

  namespace :v1, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions", registrations: "users/registrations" }
    # Routes for posts
    get 'posts(/index)', :to => 'posts#index'
    post 'posts/create'
    delete 'posts/:id', :to => 'posts#destroy'
    get 'posts/show'
    put 'posts/:id', :to => 'posts#update'
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you have in User.rb for devise?  Do you have something like this?    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :rememberable

Comment: Have you tried putting <%= current_user.remember_me! %> in the layout and seeing the output?  Also this is just a guess, but have you tried finding the user object and performing remember_me! right on the user object?

Comment: I have tried `user.remember_me!` (after finding the actual user object) and it didn't work either. Both `user.remember_me!` and `current_user.remember_me!` returned null. And I have no layouts, so I just returned the result as JSON.

Comment: Can you try the answer here?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417201/how-to-automatically-keep-user-remembered-in-devise

Comment: I've tried that solution and similar ones, still no luck.

Comment: How about this: http://dev.mensfeld.pl/2013/12/rails-devise-and-remember_me-rememberable-by-default/

Comment: I've run into that also and it doesn't work for me either.

Comment: Seems like I'm doing it wrong. Looking at questions like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30038475/rails-api-best-way-to-implement-authentication.